# Not being able to run my Jupyter notebook using Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, venv

```
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir /venv
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    curl \
    git \
    wget \
    unzip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir torch torchvision
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir transformers
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir scipy
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir jupyter
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /venv/bin/activate"]
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir \
    pymongo \
    express
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The above is is my dockerfile and I've successfully installed all the dependencies, but I am not able to run `jupyter nbconvert --execute ${notebookPath} --to notebook --output ${notebookPath}_executed.ipynb` and getting an error of jupyter not found.

Comment: i started of with creating a venv and installing he dependencies in it, still not being able to exec the command

Comment: You seem to be installing dependencies, and then creating and activating a brand new environment after that.

Comment: you should activate venv first and install all deps after that plus would be better manage everything in requirement.txt

Comment: can you help me with the corrections?

Comment: that's first normal change to try with enable venv first and other command after that change in order of in your existing file

Comment: RUN python3 -m venv venv
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-c", "source venv/bin/activate"]
RUN pip3 install torch==1.9.0 torchvision && \
    pip3 install spacy notebook scipy && \
    pip3 install jupyter && \
    RUN pip3 install ipykernel ipywidgets && \
    python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir .
ADD src/middleware venv/src/middleware
CMD ["npm", "start", "--allow-root"]
i did that @HarshManvar sir,still got the error -> jupyter not found. :(

Comment: where you are running command and seeing error ?

Comment: i did docker run -d -p 3000:3000 <imageid>,hit the api using postman, went back to the docker container and checked the console.

Comment: that's the issue of venv change order activate it before you install deps and try